# How to select the proper SQL Server instance when upgrading from SQL Express 2008 to SQL Express 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade from SQL Express 2008 to SQL Express 2008 R2 to enable the full text indexing feature. During the upgrade, at the "Select Instance" step, the database that should be upgraded is not present in the drop down list.

Below the drop down there is a section titled "Installed instances".  There are 4 items in this list, 3 SQL Servers and one entry for "shared components".

The drop down list contains 2 items, the first SQL Server in the "installed instances" list and the "shared components" but it does not list the other 2 SQL Servers.

The SQL Server that is included in the drop down is a Express Edition version 10.1.2531.0.  The Shared Components version is 10.50.1600.1.

The 2 SQL Servers that are not appearing in the list are both Express Editions, version 10.52.4000.0.

Why aren't these 2 SQL Servers showing up in the list that allows me to specify the instance to upgrade?

Here is a screenshot of the step I am referencing:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: When you upgrade to a new version of SQL, you are upgrading a SQL instance.  Not a database, per se.  An instance of the Database Engine is a copy of the sqlservr.exe executable that runs as an operating system service. Each instance manages several system databases and one or more user databases. Each computer can run multiple instances of the Database Engine. Applications connect to the instance in order to perform work in a database managed by the instance.

Comment: @DMason - Does this mean that selecting the SHAREPOINT instance will also upgrade the other instances that are listed?

Comment: No.  You can only upgrade one instance at a time.  That's what the "Select Instance" step in the installation wizard is prompting you for.

Comment: So this brings me back to the original question... Why are the middle two database engines not available in the drop down list?

Comment: The SQL instances that are version 10.52.4000.0 are already SQL Server 2008 R2 (with SP2).  You can't "upgrade" them.  Does that make sense?  http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/recent-sql-server-build-numbers

Comment: Thanks for that info and that makes perfect sense.  I am trying to upgrade to the version with Advanced Tools so the full text indexing can be enabled.  I am guessing the install file I downloaded wasn't the most recent.  I am investigating that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't upgrade the SQL instances that are version 10.52.4000.0 to SQL Express 2008 R2 because they are already SQL Server 2008 R2 (with SP2).

Check out a list of [SQL Server build numbers](http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/) for more details.